# Estado en react no concuerda con el valor en Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando el hook useState para controlar un formulario así:

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({ url: '', title: '', description: '' });
const handleChange = e => {
    setForm({ ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log({form});
};
```

El componente retorna varios inputs así:

```
                <input
                    name='title'
                    value={form.title}
                    type='text'
                    required={true}
                    placeholder='Título'
                    onChange={handleChange}'
                />
```

Pero este código hace que el estado no concuerde con el valor en los inputs, el estado siempre está un caractér atrasado, es decir que si en input el valor es `'hola mundo'`, en el estado el valor será `'hola mund'`, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Para entender bien porqué pasa eso, te recomiendo que leas este articulo  [Dentro de la caja negra de “setState”](https://desarrollos-web-urquiza.medium.com/dentro-de-la-caja-negra-de-setstate-69001c7c6ea4)

Comment: Esta muy interesante el post de @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La razón es porque `React` trabaja en base a *asincronía*, por lo que las renderizaciones o re-renderizaciones estarán *desactualizadas* en base a lo que se realiza.

Una forma de trabajar con los datos *alineados* es usar el hook **[useEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)**, el cual juega el papel ejecutar código cuando se monta el componente y/o cuando se cumple cierta condición.

Por lo que si realizas lo siguiente

```
useEffect(() => console.log(form), [form])
```

el dato estará completo, por decirlo de alguna manera.

Cualquier duda nos comentas ;)